# Redirect component of React not working as expected in axios .then() promise

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

I have a react router with the following routes:

'/' = My Main App Component
'/create' = My secondary view

In my Create view in onClick of button I issue a axios.post call to post a JSON object to an API we have.

Upon its success I set a state variable called ReturnToHome using Reacts setState({ReturnToHome : true})

In my render method I have a:

```
if (this.state.ReturnToHome) { return ( <Redirect to='/' /> )};
```

IMPORTANT: Here's the interesting thing I'm struggling with:

1) When this same this.setState call is NOT in the .then of the axios promise the redirect works flawlessly
2) When this.setState is inside of the .then of the promise it does not work.

I thought perhaps it at first it could be a scoping problem with this so I saved this to a pThis and specifically used pThis in the .then but it had no positive effect.

ALSO OF NOTE:  When I first go to my view the path is: #/create.  After I update the state with the redirect the path is ?#/create...  I'm not sure if this is relevant but hoping it may be a clue.

Any ideas as to why this doesn't work?  Perhaps even a working sample of how this is accomplished in a promise type scenario?

Comment: I think the best way to get it solved would be to create a codesandbox to see what's going on.

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure you wrapped your app hierarchy with the React-router `<Switch>` component and defined your routes properly, switch iterate over the possible available paths allow you to handle errors using the path variable.
2. It is better to write condition in render using the `&&` mark. eg: `return (this.state.ReturnToHome && <Redirect to="/" />)` and this will do the job.

Theoretically, on every state update, the component should update and will update and will render eventually, so the problem isn't in the render function.

so here is some example for your case:

```
export class App extends React.component {
.....
render() {
    return <ReactRouter>
                <Switch>
                      <Route exact path="/" render={homeComponent} />
                      <Route path="/create" render={createComponent}/></Switch> 
           </ReactRouter>
}
export class CreateComponent extends React.component {
    constructor(){
         this.state = {
              ReturnToHome: false
         }
         this.callToApi = this.callToApi.bind(this)
    }
    callToApi = e => {//e not required but always good to record event handlers......
        const self = this
        axios.post("apiuri",{params}..complete the post method requiremnets based on api..).then((response)=> {
            self.setState({ReturnToHome:true})
        })
    }
    render(){
         return ....some logic with buttons to start the callToApi method.....
         (this.state.ReturnToHome && <Redirect to="/" />)
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response.  Unfortunately Switch did not add/change any of the behavior.

Answer (score -1):

OK well I found the resolution.  In the end I narrowed it down to a single field I was modifying.  Every time I modified the field the app exhibited this strange behavior.

I began experimenting really not understanding why I was seeing this behavior and I changed the  tag that was my base element to a .

Everything started working great.  If only I knew why...

My guess is there is something about ReactJS I am still unaware of.

Hope this helps someone!

Comment: what was the original clickable element?

Comment: Hi Itay, if I understand your question correctly the original clickable element is a button within the form.  Just a standard <button>

Comment: `In the end I narrowed it down to a single field I was modifying.`  Huh? What single field were you modifying?  So no, as written this answer is not helpful.  Perhaps you can explain?

Comment: Please explain the answer with explicit solutions.